# Allow userform input from a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, wait

I have a foreach loop that I need to pause in order to allow user input on the form.

```
foreach (XmlNode node2 in xmlFile)
   {
       ...get currentRow from XML file
       ...update form label

       ???wait for user to enter data on form and press button
   }
```

Is there any sort of wait-for-user-input function in C# that I can use to do this?

UPDATE:

Based on the feedback I have successfully modified the program to:

- Load the XML list into a Queue (using the ForEach loop)
- Setup the user input to iterate through the Queue (remove top item, show next top item)

Comment: Is the input form always displayed to the user? Do you just want to pause the foreach loop when the user starts entering information?

Comment: I prefer usually to do event driven behaviours. Usually they are more clean than nesting modal forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a modal form where the user can make the input.

If you want to stay on the same form all the time you better copy all nodes to an `Queue<XmlNode>`, process one at a time and when the user presses the button pick the next item in the Queue until the queue is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Create you input form (use visual studio designer, is really simple), then show it in the loop by calling `ShowDialog()`:

```
foreach(XmlNode node2 in xmlFile)
{
   //...
   MyInputForm form = new MyInputForm();
   form.ShowDialog(); // it waits until user close the input form
   var input = form.PropertyContainingInputFromTheUser;
   //...use the input

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to do a while loop which keeps checking for a value. However; depending on how you implement this and the overall structure of the application, this might cause the application to become unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use this design.  I would have a form that shows and maybe loop using a control on the form - not displaying a new form for every instance.  Load the data into a data grid and let the user edit all of it and save at one time.